# Call UWP service on Shared project

Tags: xamarin, uwp

I have a Xamarin app where I implemented a service to do some printing. I create that service on UWP app because it needs some dependencies of it.

UWP Service:

```
 public class PrintUWPService
    {
        PrintManager printmgr = PrintManager.GetForCurrentView();
        PrintDocument PrintDoc;
        PrintDocument printDoc;
        PrintTask Task;
        private Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView ViewToPrint = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView();

        public PrintUWPService()
        {
            printmgr.PrintTaskRequested += Printmgr_PrintTaskRequested;
        }

        public async void Print(WebView viewToPrint, string htmlSource)
        {
            ViewToPrint.NavigateToString(htmlSource);

            if (PrintDoc != null)
            {
                printDoc.GetPreviewPage -= PrintDoc_GetPreviewPage;
                printDoc.Paginate -= PrintDoc_Paginate;
                printDoc.AddPages -= PrintDoc_AddPages;
            }

            printDoc = new PrintDocument();

            try
            {
                printDoc.GetPreviewPage += PrintDoc_GetPreviewPage;
                printDoc.Paginate += PrintDoc_Paginate;
                printDoc.AddPages += PrintDoc_AddPages;

                var showprint = await PrintManager.ShowPrintUIAsync();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }

            PrintDoc = null;
            GC.Collect();
        }

        private void Printmgr_PrintTaskRequested(PrintManager sender, PrintTaskRequestedEventArgs args)
        {
            var deff = args.Request.GetDeferral();
            Task = args.Request.CreatePrintTask("Grocery List", OnPrintTaskSourceRequested);

            deff.Complete();

        }
        async void OnPrintTaskSourceRequested(PrintTaskSourceRequestedArgs args)
        {
            var def = args.GetDeferral();
            await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                args.SetSource(printDoc.DocumentSource);
            });
            def.Complete();
        }

        private void PrintDoc_AddPages(object sender, AddPagesEventArgs e)
        {
            printDoc.AddPage(ViewToPrint);
            printDoc.AddPagesComplete();
        }

        private void PrintDoc_Paginate(object sender, PaginateEventArgs e)
        {
            PrintTaskOptions opt = Task.Options;
            printDoc.SetPreviewPageCount(1, PreviewPageCountType.Final);
        }

        private void PrintDoc_GetPreviewPage(object sender, GetPreviewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            printDoc.SetPreviewPage(e.PageNumber, ViewToPrint);
        }
    }
}
```

Then I create interface for it:

```
 public interface IPrintUWPService
    {
        void Print(WebView viewToPrint, string htmlSource);
    }
```

Now inside a class of my shared project I want to call this service as:

```
private readonly IPrintUWPService _printService =  DependencyService.Get<IPrintUWPService>();
```

But it does not work. it says:

> IPrintUWPService does not exist in the current context

So I try to access to UWP class as:

```
using MyCompany.ProjectName.App.UWP
```

But it says that "UWP" namespace does not exist. What am I doing wrong? is not possible call service on UWP project inside shared project? Regards

Comment: is the interface defined in the shared project?  Have you read the docs and samples for using DependencyService?

Comment: No, is not defined in shared project, how can I define? can you share with me that documentation please? @Jason

Comment: Literally move the interface file in the shared project.  The docs are the first hit on Google - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction

Comment: Awesome, thanks! @Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Call UWP DependencyService on Shared project

As @Jason mentioned in above comment, you need declare the interface in the Xamarin Forms project and implement it in the UWP client project.

And please [note](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction#register-the-platform-implementations), after implementing the interface in each platform project, the platform implementations must be registered with the `DependencyService`, so that Xamarin.Forms can locate them at runtime. Use [`DependencyAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.dependencyattribute) like the following.

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(UWP Client namesapce))]
```